# SET Statements - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having an issue with my SQL create procedure that includes set statements. Continously, I receive the following error:

```
Invalid syntax near SET. Expecting '(', SELECT or WITH.
```

This is a small snippet of the code.

```
DECLARE  @v_dynSQL varchar(8000)
DECLARE ResultSet CURSOR FOR
SET  @sYear_Desc0 = dbo.GET_YEAR_DESC(@sPlan_Period_Start_Year_Id - 1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start with the documentation on cursors:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169(v=sql.110).aspx.

Comment: what is dbo.GET_YEAR_DESC?

Comment: Already have gone through the documentation. The code is from a legacy system which makes this more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a SET statement directly after DECLARE ResultSet CURSOR FOR which is expecting a SELECT OR a WITH immediately after it. I am guessing that you initialize the CURSOR later on . Hence you could try removing "FOR" after "DECLARE ResultSet CURSOR" or move the SET statement before the DECLARE ResultSet CURSOR FOR depending on what the rest of the code does.